# Consultar banco sqlite criado pelo core data

Tags: ios, swift

Estou estudando o core data no ios. Criei um modelo e inseri alguns registros. Eu gostaria de consultar esses registros usando SQL no programa "DB Browser for sqlite", mas não sei onde o xcode cria o arquivo do banco. Alguém sabe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O arquivo do banco vai ficar nas entranhas do simulador. Para achar esse arquivo você tem duas opções.

1. No terminal vc faz o seguinte: `find ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices -name "<Nome do seu app>*.db"`
2. Instalar o OpenSim, e navegar no diretório dos arquivos do seu APP:
   `brew cask install opensim` https://github.com/luosheng/OpenSim

Comment: Consegui, obrigado :)